# How to restrict global access for solr admin DIRECTLY FROM BROWSER

Tags: php, solr

When i run the following URL I can see all the permissions open

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/
```

I now installed solr on my development  server

```
http://www.xyz.com:8983/solr/#/
```

Here, anyone can open this and can destroy the documents. How can i make it password protected ??? OR any other solution on server.

EDITED

i have added this code which results in 503 error. Can anyone check the mistake here

```
<web-app 
        id="/solr" 
        document-directory="/home/admin1/solr-4.2.1/example/"
        archive-path="/home/admin1/solr-4.2.1/example/webapps/solr.war"
        character-encoding="utf-8">

       <system-property solr.solr.home="/home/admin1/solr-4.2.1/example/solr/collection1/data" />

       <authenticator type="com.caucho.server.security.XmlAuthenticator">
          <init>
            <user>user:user12345:user,admin</user>
            <password-digest>none</password-digest>
          </init>
        </authenticator>
       <security-constraint url-pattern='/admin/*' role-name='user'/>
      </web-app>
```

I have added this in

```
example/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Comment: Is this running through Apache? If so, do a search here for "htaccess password protection" - plenty of answers to get you started!

Comment: do i have to put .htaccess in example/solr/ path ? OR where ?

Comment: @halfer If we use htaccess password protection looks like whole site will need that authentication whereas I think user needs only that solr folder to have that authenitication.

Comment: @chandresh: No, you can restrict it - I think the `Location` directive would do that. Or, as Sandy says, an `.htaccess` file in the folder that needs protection - assuming "solr" is a real folder.

Comment: halfer - I added the .htaccess in the folder where my admin.html file exists. Which didn't work ! where exactly i need to add my .htaccess ???

Comment: yea, where exactly to add htaccess ?!!

Answer (score 0):

The [Solr Security](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity) page on the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr) has a lot of good suggestions for ways to restrict access to all or parts of Solr.

Comment: I followed the link and i added the code for authentication, it is not working though. Can you check the edited code above.

Comment: Are you using Resin as your web server/framework? The code you added is specific for Resin. Based on your path, looks like you are using Jetty, so you would need to follow the Common Servlet and Jetty examples.

Comment: I tried with jetty and common servlet methods. There was no change. FYI i copied the method as is and tried. Can you give elaborate on the changes required like path settings OR authentication settings OR code settings etc...